# Pandas Groupby: Aggregations on the same columns but multiple totals based on multiple critera

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

A question on aggregation but this time the totals are on multiple fields, one set based on a criteria and the second set on grand totals. My df:

```
display_name    security_type1  currency_str    state   rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv
A                     GOVT           USD        Done        100,000
B                     CORP           NZD        Passed      100,000
B                     CORP           USD        Done        100,000
C                     CORP           EUR        Done        100,000
C                     CORP           EUR        Traded Away 100,000
C                     CORP           GBP        Done        100,000
C                     CORP           GBP        Done        100,000
C                     CORP           USD        Done        100,000
```

Desired output follows:

```
           display_name security_type1  currency_str    Done_RFQ    Done_RFQ_Volume 
                A               GOVT            USD             1           100,000         
                B               CORP            USD             1           100,000
                C               CORP            EUR             1           100,000
                C               CORP            GBP             2           200,000
                C               CORP            USD             1           100,000

            Total_RFQ   Total RFQ_Volume    Done_Pct
                1           100,000         100%
                2           200,000         50%
                5           500,000         20%
                5           500,000         40%
                5           500,000         20%
```

That is:

1. Group on `display_name`,`security_type1`and `currency_str`
2. `Done_RFQ` is the row count where `state`contains any string with `Done` in it.
3. `Done_RFQ_Volume` is the sum of `rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv` where `state`contains any string with `Done` i.e. where point 2 is true.
4. `Total_RFQ` is the count of all unique `display_name`,`security_type1`and `currency_str` combinations regardless if `Done` appears for `state` and
5. `Total RFQ_Volume` is the sum of `rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv` for all records where point 4 is true.
6. Finally display the percentage of Done to total count i.e. `Done_Pct` = `Done_RFQ` / `Total_RFQ`

My attept at achieving this:

```
d = [
     ('Done_RFQ', lambda x: x.str.contains('Done').sum())    
     ('Done_RFQ_Volume', 'sum'), 
     ('Total_RFQ', 'size'), 
     ('Total RFQ_Volume', 'sum')      
    ]
df_Done_Client_Hit_Rate_Volume = df.groupby(['cust_cdr_display_name','rbc_security_type1','currency_str']).agg(d).reset_index()
df_Done_Client_Hit_Rate_Volume['Hit Rate'] = df_Done_Client_Hit_Rate_Volume['Done_RFQ'] / df_Done_Client_Hit_Rate_Volume['Total_RFQ'] 
display(df_Done_Client_Hit_Rate_Volume)
```

I'm not sure how to refer to the 'Done' rows and not 'Done' rows when summing rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv.  The two volume columns (set out in d=), are based on the results of the criteria. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you check column `Total RFQ_Volume` ? Because there is difference between my and your output. Thanks.

Comment: yes checking now. Confirmed bug on my end, question updated

Comment: There is my problem if want grouping by all 3 columns output is different, if want gruoping by column `display_name` output is good for `Total_RFQ` only. So question is need `.groupby(['display_name','security_type1','currency_str'])` or `df.groupby(['display_name'])`  for `Total` columns ?

Comment: Totals are based on client so df.groupby(['display_name'])

Comment: OK, then it is correct.

Comment: works a gem!! Thanks again @jezrael

Comment: One additional touch up. If we wanted to sort the Total RFQ_Volume within each client what needs to be added? So want to see the highest trades first for each client.

Comment: Do you think for each `display_name` get top  `Total RFQ_Volume` value? If yes, it have logic problem. Because for each `display_name` is same value `Total RFQ_Volume` - you can see it in `df2`. Can you explain more?

Comment: Yes ideally to view the client with the highest Total_RFQ_Volume first, show that clients other rows then show the next client which has the next highest Total_RFQ_Volume. So in the example C woulud be first, then C's other two records followed by B then A

Comment: I get you, give me asec.

Comment: I think need `print (df_Done_Client_Hit_Rate_Volume.sort_values(['Total RFQ_Volume', 'display_name'], ascending=[False, True]))`

Comment: yes works well. Thanks again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174850/discussion-between-peter-lucas-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert column to numeric if necessary
df['rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv'] = df['rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv'].str.replace(',','').astype(int)

d = [
     ('Done_RFQ_Volume', 'sum'), 
     ('Done_RFQ', 'size'), 
    ]

#first filter by substring and then aggregate of filtered df
mask = df['state'].str.contains('Done')
df1 = (df[mask].groupby(['display_name','security_type1','currency_str'])['rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv']
               .agg(d)
               .reset_index())

print (df1)
  display_name security_type1 currency_str  Done_RFQ_Volume  Done_RFQ
0            A           GOVT          USD           100000         1
1            B           CORP          USD           100000         1
2            C           CORP          EUR           100000         1
3            C           CORP          GBP           200000         2
4            C           CORP          USD           100000         1
```

---

```
d = [
     ('Total RFQ_Volume', 'sum'), 
     ('Total_RFQ', 'size'), 
    ]

#aggregate by column display_name only
df2 = df.groupby(['display_name'])['rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv'].agg(d)
print (df2)
              Total RFQ_Volume  Total_RFQ
display_name                             
A                       100000          1
B                       200000          2
C                       500000          5

#join both df together
df_Done_Client_Hit_Rate_Volume = df1.join(df2, on='display_name')
df_Done_Client_Hit_Rate_Volume['Hit Rate'] = df_Done_Client_Hit_Rate_Volume['Done_RFQ'] / 
                                              df_Done_Client_Hit_Rate_Volume['Total_RFQ']
```

---

```
print (df_Done_Client_Hit_Rate_Volume)
  display_name security_type1 currency_str  Done_RFQ_Volume  Done_RFQ  \
0            A           GOVT          USD           100000         1   
1            B           CORP          USD           100000         1   
2            C           CORP          EUR           100000         1   
3            C           CORP          GBP           200000         2   
4            C           CORP          USD           100000         1   

   Total RFQ_Volume  Total_RFQ  Hit Rate  
0            100000          1       1.0  
1            200000          2       0.5  
2            500000          5       0.2  
3            500000          5       0.4  
4            500000          5       0.2
```